# “borrowed value does not live long enough” when using .lines()

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to read text through a buffer and then calculate how many times each single word appears in the text:

```
let mut word_map: HashMap<&str, isize> = HashMap::new();
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
for line in reader.lines() {
    for mut curr in line.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
        match word_map.entry(curr) {
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => {
                *entry.into_mut() += 1;
            }
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                entry.insert(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a `HashMap` with words as keys and their frequencies in text as value. If a new word is found its value is one otherwise its value gets incremented.

I'm constantly getting this error and cannot find a way out. I've tried to use `let` before the inner loop, but I still get the same error stating that temporary value

```
    error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:32:2
   |
26 |   for mut curr in line.as_ref().unwrap().split_whitespace(){
   |                   ---- borrow occurs here
...
32 |  }
   |  ^ `line` dropped here while still borrowed
33 |
34 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I'm having trouble finding why `line` has to live until the end of main and why it gets dropped while still borrowed. Why am I having this error?

Comment: When you do `word_map.entry(curr)` and then potentially insert that entry, you are borrowing `curr` for the lifetime of that `HashMap`. You will probably need to copy or own that value. (Disclaimer: I don't know rust)

Comment: @Score_Under close, but not quite. `split_whitespace` returns references to the original string, but that memory will be dropped at the end of loop.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks, that solved the problem.